# Rating Form in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, require, extjs6

I am trying to copy the example rating form from [Sencha's online examples](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#form-rating). I do not understand why I am getting this error:

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\classic\src\view\form\RatingForm.js::ClassRequire::Ext.ux.rating.Picker
[ERR]   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.
[ERR] java:99)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 3 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:247: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\.sencha\app\watch-impl.xml:61: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:380: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for C:\users\Diederiksj\Desktop\FreshApp\classic\src\view\form\RatingForm.js::ClassRequire::Ext.ux.rating.Picker
```

When I look in `AppRootDirectory/ext/packages/ux/classic/src/rating`, the `Picker.js` file is there, automatically created by ExtJS when generating the app. Here is an excerpt from the class where I try to require the Picker class:

```
Ext.define('FreshApp.view.form.RatingForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'form-rating',

    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.rating.Picker'
    ],

    title: 'Rating Form',
    viewModel: true,

    bodyPadding: 10,
    width: 520,
    height: 500,
    minHeight: 400,
    resizable: true,
    frame: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaultType: 'textfield',
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have in your app.js something like `paths: {'Ext.ux': 'path/to/ux/'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that you app requires ux package. You can do that by adding the following snippet in your app.json.

```
"requires": [
    "ux"
],
```

Comment: I can't try it again until tomorrow, but to my recollection, I did not add any require statement to ```app.json```. I will be sure to give you both +1 if it works. Thanks.

Comment: i dint find app.json in extjs 4.2.2 , how can i fix this issue in extjs 4.2.2?